# courseraのmachine learningのプログラミング課題について: warning: opengl_renderer: data values greater than float capacity

Tags: 機械学習, octave

courseraのmachine learning講座をやりはじめたのですが、week2のプログラミング課題の任意課題（ex1_multi）を実行すると下記のようにwarningが発生してしまいます。
原因はなんでしょうか？宜しくお願いします。

```
Loading data ...
First 10 examples from the dataset:
 x = [2104 3], y = 399900
 x = [1600 3], y = 329900
 x = [2400 3], y = 369000
 x = [1416 2], y = 232000
 x = [3000 4], y = 539900
 x = [1985 4], y = 299900
 x = [1534 3], y = 314900
 x = [1427 3], y = 198999
 x = [1380 3], y = 212000
 x = [1494 3], y = 242500
Program paused. Press enter to continue.
Normalizing Features ...
Running gradient descent ...
Theta computed from gradient descent:
 NaN
 NaN
 NaN

Predicted price of a 1650 sq-ft, 3 br house (using gradient descent):
 $0.000000
Program paused. Press enter to continue.
warning: opengl_renderer: data values greater than float capacity.  (1) Scale da
ta, or (2) Use gnuplot
warning: called from
    ex1_multi at line 117 column 1
Solving with normal equations...
Theta computed from the normal equations:
 89597.909541
 139.210674
 -8738.019112

Predicted price of a 1650 sq-ft, 3 br house (using normal equations):
 $0.000000
```

> warning: opengl_renderer: data values greater than float capacity.  (1) Scale data, or (2) Use gnuplot

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問ですが、coursera の当該コースに登録している方でないと元々の問題やソースコードを確認できず、なかなか回答が集まりにくいと思います。可能であれば（著作権など法的に問題なさそうであれば）、関係しそうなソースコードも追記いただくなどして情報を増やして頂きたいです。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Andrew Ng のコースでOctaveをお使いでしょうか。

Comment: はい、その通りです。Andrew Ng のコースでOctaveです。必須課題は問題なく解けたのですが任意課題が上記のwarningが発生してうまく動作しません。

Answer (score 1):

theta の計算結果は

```
Theta computed from gradient descent:
 NaN
 NaN
 NaN
```

となっていますが、NaNというのは、例えば0を0で割ったときに出る異常値ですので、計算に失敗しています。おそらくプロットデータにも異常な値が入っているため、warningが発生しているのでしょう。

cost functionやgradient descentのコードを見直してみてください。